# Why do we need the custom dataset class and use of _getitem_ method in NLP, BERT fine tuning etc

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am a newbie in NLP and has been studying the usage of BERT for NLP tasks. In many notebooks, I See that a custom dataset class is defined and *getitem* method is defined (along with len).

Tweetdataset class in this notebook - https://www.kaggle.com/abhishek/roberta-inference-5-folds

and text_Dataset class in this notebook - https://engineering.wootric.com/when-bert-meets-pytorch

Can some one please explain the reason, need for defining the custom dataset class and the *getitem* (and len) method. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a recommended abstraction in pytorch to define `datasets` by inheriting [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset). Those objects define how many elements are there (`__len__` method) and how to get a single item via specified index (`__getitem__(index)`).

Its [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataset.html#Dataset):

```
class Dataset(object):   
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __add__(self, other):
        return ConcatDataset([self, other])
```

So it's basically a thin wrapper which adds possibility to concatenate two `Dataset` objects. For readability and API compatibility you should inherit from it (unlike the one provided in `kaggle`).

You can read more about PyTorch's data functionality [**here**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset)

Comment: Thank you @Szymon. I see this in the docs "All datasets that represent a map from keys to data samples should subclass it.". Can you please elaborate the need/requirement for subclassing the 'Dataset' class. I am sorry, I couldn't understand it from this statement and your 'adds possibility to concatenate......readability and API compatibility' statement. Is this specific to pytorch or is it similar approach in tensorflow as well

Comment: It is specific to PyTorch. In `tensorflow` the closest I can think of is [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly) probably. It is not necessary to inherit from `torch.utils.data.Dataset` in most cases (as far as I can tell) but it is a good practice and prevalent in PyTorch community. Additionally, when you inherit, you get `__add__` method (see above) which allows for dataset concatenation. And yes, `dataset` as an object with `__getitem__` is almost always needed for anything serious PyTorch (so might as well stick to it all the time).